# Change Installshield project in configuration manager to debug

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, deployment, app-config, installshield

I have a WPF application.. I need to create 3 setups, each setup is for an environment(development, staging and production), I've put each environment configuration into App.config file of my main UI project. I need Installshield to pull the appropriate configuration file while creating the setup file.

A question: Is there a way to do it differently?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you could take. Here's one:

In recent versions of InstallShield (Professional and higher editions), you can override Path Variables on a per-Release basis. If you craft your source filesystem and source path correctly, this should let you select from multiple source app.config files just by building a different release.

Comment: Do you have an example for this approach?